# Using android camera with an explicit intent

Tags: android

I want to build an app that simply takes pictures without using another app to do it. I saw in examples that implicit intents are used to take pictures. But i want to do it with an explicit intent if it's possible and i want to know  how to design the layout of the camera activity.
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_camera.htm. it has both implicit and explicit INTENT camera tutorial.

But they have used Camera API which is deprecated, use Camera2(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) Api which is replace for deprecated camera API